# How many cells table view uses

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have 100 rows of data but when we i run the code in iPhone Retina(4-inch) simulator i can see only 14 fit on the screen at a time. If i count the number of visible rows then i get up to 13 but it’s possible to scroll the table in such a way that the top cell is still visible and a new cell is pulled in from below. So that makes at least 14 cells.
If you scroll really fast, then I guess it is possible that the table view needs to make a few more temporary cells, but I’m not sure about that.I want to know after how many cells a cell get reused?

Comment: You have already answered your own question. The table creates as many cells as are needed to fill the screen.

Comment: Actually,i needed to be assured whether my assumption is correct or not.Now, i know that my assumption is correct.Anyway,Thanks for your comment!